# Jquery - When hovered multiple times frequently, element still shakes for a long time

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I leave mouse from my container it bounces up and down.
But the problem here is when I do this continuously(very fast) for some time, and then stop doing it, it still shakes for a long time.
So basically i want my animation to stop as soon I leave my last mouse from the container.
PS - I have already tried `$('.container').stop()`.
Imagine it as you are frequently hovering the element very fast.(Without letting the previous animation to finish)
Then you stop suddenly.
So the animation should also stop. but it dont!
This is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/WKy56/

This is my jquery code :

```
$('.container').mouseleave(function(){
    doBounce($('.container'), 2, '10px', 50);
}); 

function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
    for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        element.animate({marginTop: '-='+distance}, speed)
        .animate({marginTop: '+='+distance}, speed);
    }  
}
```

PSS - If u cant answer or cant understand the question read the comments below and atleast dont vote this down. Its a genuine problem for many.

Comment: _"as soon I leave my last mouse from the container."_ What? You have 2 mice attached to your PC? Joking aside, How are we supposed to know what the "last" mouseleave is?

Comment: Can you please JSFiddle to demonstrate this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `.stop()` or `.finish()`

Comment: Imagine it as you are frequently hovering the element very fast.(Without letting the previous animation to finish)
Then you stop suddenly.
So the animation should also stop. but it dont!

Comment: @jackkorbin Instead of letting us 'imagine', why don't you simply replicate your issue on jsFiddle???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WKy56/
Here it is.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Did you continuously hover it for some time and leave? Even your stop function is making the div go upwards!!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I just want my animation to stop completely after i leave my mouse from the container last time. What it does now is it keeps on going.
PS - I am only talking about the case wen u hovered the container very fastly for some in out in out type..

Comment: As it worked fine for me *I obviously do not understand what you are talking about*. Go with `Jack Black`'s nice simple solution below.

Comment: I think i shud take a video now -_-

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WKy56/1/
Open it.
Just hold your mouse and shake it across the div like a KID.
Stop suddenly and den watch the div to bounce many more times.
I dont want this. I want the animation to stop right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.container').not(':animated').mouseleave(...
```

edit: this should be enough:

```
$('.container').mouseleave(function(){
    doBounce($('.container').not(':animated'), 2, '10px', 50);
});
```

Comment: I think I prefer your solution. "do not animate if already animating" :) Nice and simple and avoids the creeping effect completely.

Comment: I think the real problem is that we don't actually know what the problem is (arrrrgh!!!) :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue if I add the .not(':animiated') to both $('.container') selectors (it should also work only inside the mouseleave event. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I think is to use .finish() on the element since it finishes the animation and doesn't leave the incorrect top margin value that needs to be reset.

```
$('.container').mouseleave(function(){
    doBounce($('.container'), 2, '10px', 50);
}); 

function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
    element.finish();
    for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        element.animate({marginTop: '-='+distance}, speed)
        .animate({marginTop: '+='+distance}, speed);
    }  
}
```

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xA5C/) for this.